# Archiving whole result of a Twitter Hashtag serach

Tags: twitter, export, social-networking, archiving, data-processing

Is there a [data processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_processing) tool that allow to countinuously download the result of a Hashtag search in https://search.twitter.com, or that just allow to download the whole tweets of the specific hashtag (data scraper)? 'The Archivist Desktop' is the only one I founded, it allow to export the whole result to `CSV` Format and it's a paying one. Is there a free alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is using a service such as [GNIP](http://www.gnip.com) or [Datasift](http://www.datasift.com). Both have Twitter streams and their purpose in life is delivering data for analytics. Datasift has the ability to create a dataset which can be downloaded. I haven't tried it, but it should work for your purpose.

Comment: I almost forgot, [Splunk](http://splunk.com) is ofcourse a great tool that can be used to collect data. There is a free version that allows upto **500Mb/day** data collection.